# WPF - Border doesn't show in a window but shows in another one

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am currently developing paint application with a chat in C#/WPF and I am having a little problem with the borders.
I created a Page named `ChatSection.xaml` that contains all my chat UI and logic, and I'm adding it to two different windows using the `Frame` tag like this :

ChatWindow.xaml

```
<Frame Source="/Vues/ChatSection.xaml" />
```

FenetreDessin.xaml (sorry its in French, this code was already done when I started)

```
<Frame Name="chatSection" Source="/Vues/ChatSection.xaml" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
```

The application is made in a way that the chat first appears in the window `FenetreDessin` and there is a button on this window to separate the chat from `FenetreDessin` like this :

FenetreDessin with chat included

[FenetreDessin window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL0Gf.png)

ChatWindow extracted

[ChatWindow window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRyab.png)

I just made the top section of the chat (where the "< Back" is displayed) and I wanted to add a border at the bottom of it. It worked in `FenetreDessin` but not in `ChatWindow`...

FenetreDessin

[FenetreDessin chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY5Tg.png)

ChatWindow

[ChatWindow chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96PpE.png)

Here's the code I just added for the bar on top in `ChatSection.xaml`

```
<Border Name="chatSection" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="{StaticResource chatWidth}" BorderThickness="0.5,0.5,0,0" BorderBrush="#77000000">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Navigation Bar -->
        <Border Background="White" Padding="5,2,0,2" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FF0289F7" FontSize="15">
                &lt; Back
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>

        Other stuff...

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: It might be related to the fact that your border is less than one point thick.  What happens if you set the thickness to `1.0` instead of `0.5`?  I would also set `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on both windows (or on the top-level content of those windows).

Comment: Just found a solution! I specified the color with `BorderBrush="Gray"`and it worked! Thank you @MikeStrobel for your answer though!